# R: scaling , legends and the axis with barplots

Tags: r, plot

I'm having problems with my legend, scaling my text and naming individual axis

Code:

```
youtube_1 <- c(1)
youtube_2 <- c(2)
youtube <- rbind( youtube_1 , youtube_2)

facebook_1 <- c(6)
facebook_2 <- c(3)
facebook <- rbind( facebook_1 , facebook_2)

twitter_1 <- c(3)
twitter_2 <- c(1)

twitter <- rbind(twitter_1 , twitter_2)


groups <- rbind(youtube , space , facebook , space , twitter , space)


barplot(
  groups , 
  main="Rating" ,
  ylab="Number of votes over time (people under 50 vs, people over 50)" ,
  xlab="Year 1 , Year 2 , Year 3 " ,
  col=c("yellow" , "green" ) ,
  beside=TRUE ,
  ylim= range(0 , 10) ,
 legend("topright" , legend=c("Young" , "Old") , col=c("yellow" , "green")) ,
  )
```

When I let R do it's thing, it give me:

1. a graph is hidden behind my legend :(
2. the y-axis's scale is too large compared to the graph
3. individual bars are not labeled
4. I also get this ugly error:

   Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
   In addition: Warning message:
   In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I want:

1. The legend to move away from the graph "area"
2. scale the text of the axis
3. label each individual bar
4. label an individual point on the y-axis (e.g. 5) and ideally draw a line through that point

I'm also new to R, so go slowly and for dummies please :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time seeing exactly what your issues are, as "space" is not a well-defined object.

The "*Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator In addition: Warning message: In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA*" is stemming from improperly specifying the legend.  You either need to use args.legend within barplot()

```
args.legend = list(x = "topleft", col=c("yellow","green"), legend=c("Young","Old"))
```

or an alternative solution is to specify the legend after the fact:

```
barplot(
 groups , 
  main="Rating" ,
  ylab="Number of votes over time (people under 50 vs, people over 50)" ,
  xlab="Year 1 , Year 2 , Year 3 " ,
  col=c("yellow" , "green" ) ,
  beside=TRUE ,
  ylim= range(0 , 10) ,
)

legend("topright" , legend=c("Young" , "Old") , col=c("yellow" , "green"))
```

You can specify labels for each bar by using the names in barchart() and can specify the size of the names using cex.names:

```
barplot(
  groups , 
  main="Rating" ,
  ylab="Number of votes over time (people under 50 vs, people over 50)" ,
  names=row.names(groups),
  cex.names=0.75
  col=c("yellow" , "green" ) ,
  beside=TRUE ,
  ylim= range(0 , 10) ,
)
```